# Java - Best way to set properties of an object

Tags: java, object-oriented-design, performance, coding-standards, object

I don't know if there is any difference in performance, or its just a matter of choice, but I am a perfectionist like that, and I'd like to know.

Lets say you have the object `HolySheet`. You can set its properties in three ways:

```
HolySheet sheet = new HolySheet().setPropertyOne("asd").setPropertyTwo("foo");
```

or

```
HolySheet sheet = new HolySheet();
sheet.setPropertyOne("bdg")
     .setPropertyTwo("harry potter");
```

or

```
HolySheet sheet = new HolySheet();
sheet.setPropertyOne("bdg");
sheet.setPropertyTwo("harry potter");
```

Is there any difference between these 3 ways? I am interested in performance mostly.

Comment: Write them down and compare the resulting byte code.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Let me try to put it politely: If you don't know what byte code is, then you probably shouldn't worry about micro-performance optimisation in Java.

Comment: so these 3 examples will have only microscopic differences in their execution?

Comment: In all likelihood they will have absolutely no difference in their execution, but if they are to have any difference, then that difference will be at most microscopic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to ask the question, you don't need to know the answer.

If you had a profiler, profiled your code, and found this to be a hotspot, you could trivially find out the answer yourself by simply changing the code and profiling again.

Since you haven't done that, we can readily deduce that in fact, you have no such hotspot and no such profiler, and therefore, even if one of them was theoretically faster, this would be a meaningless waste of your time.

The important thing to take away is not to waste time micro-optimizing random chunks of code, because you'll spend time for literally no useful reward whatsoever. Which one of these is faster is irrelevant.